# Check if string consists only of alphanumeric, white spaces, apostrophes, dashes or dots

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string, unicode

I'm trying to select all customers who has an invalid name.

Allowed characters in names are:
   - All Unicode letters [a-z][A-Z] and other letters such as  (á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, etc...)
   - All numbers [0-9]
   - These special characters only (white spaces, apostrophes, dashes, dots)

This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customers c 
WHERE c.name TRIM(c.name) NOT REGEXP '^[[:alpha:]]+$');
```

This selects all customers whose names has any non alphanumeric characters. I need to allow white spaces, apostrophes, dashes and dots too.

Examples:

```
    ábc é --> good
    á bcd --> good
    abc  déf --> good
    ab cd éf --> good
    a-1 b4. --> good
    a 123-- --> good
    a 12'34 .-56 --> good

    ábc" é --> bad (has double quotes)
    á [bcd] --> bad (has square brackets)
    ab    déf --> bad (has a tab)
    ab *cd* éf --> bad (has *)
    (a-1 b4.) --> bad (has brackets)
```

Comment: Did you consider following remark to [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp): *The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multi-byte safe and may produce unexpected results with multi-byte character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal.*

Comment: @VMai well I'm not comparing them against a certain character. I'm just checking to see if it is alphanumeric or not. Shouldn't that evade the whole multi-byte problem?!

Comment: can you throw in some data for us to work with?

Comment: have you tried a positive list for the things you want? aka `AND TRIM(c.name) REGEXP '[-]'` would return all that match the first regexp and also those that have the -

Comment: @JohnRuddell well the solution may be that simple, but my regex skills  are close to zero :)

Comment: as are mine :) its different in mysql than other things.. if it was a regular regex match I could do it :(